# Reformatting Reports in Excel & setting Proper case

Tags: reporting, formula-field, excel

When I export a report from Salesforce into Excel, I am unable to make any field proper...it will just display =proper(A1)  It won't actually change A1 from lake tahoe to Lake Tahoe.

Please help!!

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Export Details, the default format for your cells in Excel will be Text. Just change the cell format to General & =PROPER() will work.

You can also download the file in Printable View and the formula will work without any changes to the format of the cells.

Bear in mind that the file format will be set to Web Page as default so if you want to preserve the formula's having made the changes, save the file as a workbook.

It might be easier to create a formula field to convert the text in Salesforce & then do the export, using

```
=UPPER(LEFT(field_name,1))&LOWER(Mid(field_name, 2, Len(field_name)-1))
```